# Having trouble to concatenate multiple images with OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have 408 images (256 x 256 pixels). I want to stack them horizontally and vertically to create one big image, but I've had trouble doing so. Files are named 5-X-1.jpg and they're all in the same directory.

If I can manage to generate one single row, I should be able to generate the rest. I've managed to make a list with the paths of these images, but I can't make `cv2.imread` read this array and stack it horizontally with `cv2.hconcat` or `cv2.hstack`. Error returned is "Can't convert object of type 'list' to 'str' for 'filename'".

This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
PathList = [] # empty list
InitialTermCol = 0

for imgs in range(16):
    ImgRowStack = r'C:\Users\total\Desktop\Angry\AUTOPY\JapanSteal' + '\\5-' + str(InitialTermCol) + '-1.jpg'
    PathList.append(ImgRowStack)
    InitialTermCol = InitialTermCol + 1

images = cv2.imread(PathList)
hor = np.hstack(PathList)

cv2.imshow('Horizontal', hor)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the Pathlist, to access the path to the images. Not read a list. Pathlist is in the form :Pathlist=["pathto1","pathto2","pathto3"] . So iterating over it will give you the path to the images.

`for d in PathList:                                                                                 \\   images = cv2.imread(d)                                                                                                  \\   Fullimage = np.hstack((Fullimage,images))`

If this answers helps you, please accept it!

Comment: Thanks for your answering! I can't get it to work yet!

When using:

`for d in PathList:
    images = cv2.imread(d)
    FullImage = np.hstack((FullImage, images))`

Returns an error telling me that FullImage is not defined. If I take the third line of code out of the loop, then it's images what is undefined!

Comment: FullImage is something YOU needs to define, initialize it with zeros or set Fulligame equal to your first image.